# How to run Chromium with incognito flag as default?

Tags: google-chrome, dock, startup

I have installed Ungoogled Chromium for Apple Silicon M1 from here: 92.0.4515.131-1: Binaries for macOS 64-bit ARM ("Apple Silicon") and now I would like to start it in incognito mode by default.

I know how to do that in Linux but I am clueless how to do that in macOS.

How to do that? Where does one edit the starting command for an app?

Comment: Anybody with some meaningful solution to this problem? I can't believe this is impossible to do on Mac.

Comment: does something like _open -na "Chromium" --args --incognito "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"_  in the terminal work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. But how to make it run when I click on the Chromium icon in Dock?

Comment: e.g. write a (single line) shell script and call it from AppleScript or put in a wrapper like platypus and give it a nice icon.

Comment: two possible other options - try using a plist file or something like _defaults write com.google.chrome IncognitoModeOn -integer=1_ in the terminal - well, something similar, if available. Check the Chromium docs.